# Cross domain requests using Angular & NodeJs (CORS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, cors, cross-domain

I am trying to do cross-domain requests (GET, POST, DELETE...) with Angular and NodeJs via CORS. I am successful when I try on Chrome browser but on IE11 on Win7 I get errors below.

```
SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for http://master.domain:1300/login required Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

SEC7119: XMLHttpRequest for http://master.domain:1300/login required CORS preflight.

SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
```

Master domain side I set header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` so successfully working on Chrome.

I have tried [xdomain](https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain) library but I could not succeed with Angular. I may miss something but I do not know what. There is no example on the internet.

What can I do to work this on IE? I can use any other way except CORS.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Normally since IE10, CORS is natively supported. And for IE8&9 you need to use XDomainRequest function. What is the configuration of your CORS configuration on your master request?

Comment: I set headers like :   

res.setHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'deny');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PATCH, OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

Comment: What kind of Content-Type headers do you set?

Comment: On client side(Angular2) while requesting I set  'Content-Type':'application/json' .

Comment: You need to set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type on the server side CORS configuration

Comment: Actually on both DomainA and DomainB server side I use : res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');  But when I check details on IE I have not seen any response headers(you can see my first comment) which I set manually.

Answer (score 1):

Just setting "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header might not be enough, dependent on the type of request you're making. You should also set the "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" and "Access-Control-Allow-Headers"

As an example:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

Comment: I set all headers like you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code in nodejs side it's working

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});
```